Nama stotam in tantric texts or agamas needs initiation?
Taking Namas  into account

They can be chanted without initiation.
No restrictions are there on how to chant.

There are stotrams on nama like 108 or 1008. For devi namas they are usually taken from agamas. As we are aware reading tantric texts/agamas requires initiation(don't have proper reference).
Does it mean, these stotrams requires initiation?
As they are part of agamas/tantric text.( E.g. lalita sahasranama requires initiation)

You can recite .. it is not desired though that you do the anaga nyasas etc
